# eclipse Charset for working with Windows & Linux on same Project

Tags: windows, linux, eclipse, utf-8, character-encoding

If you take a Project, where other Developers before work with the defaultsetting on Windows Eclipse installations (cp1250)... what can you do to come clear with your linux-installation of eclipse?

Or even, if you still work on Linux, and the other Developers work on windows, and don't wan't to change there settings?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recommend to set eclipse Charsetting by default on UTF-8 instead of cp1250.

Here the Solution:

1. Create a separately Workspace for all your cp1250-encoded Projects
2. Go to Window > Pereferences > General > Workspace Type cp1250 into
   the dropdownbox (*if not in the list, your have to **type** it!!*)
3. Maybe, if it's a Problem, choose "line delemiter" Windows (For me the default-setting always work, so i doesn't need to change it anyway!)

Here a Screenshot off it:
[image: Config looks like this]

Save it, and your done.

Comment: Key part being "if not in the list, your have to type it!!" +1

Comment: Related https://superuser.com/questions/427024/cp1250-encoded-source-code-on-eclipse-linux

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion there might be great "hassle" when changing the default text-file encoding from Cp1252 on windows to utf-8 globally, because it changes the system property file.encoding also when executing a program from eclipse. I had the case recently where a eclipse based product did not work the same way when I exported it because of a non-default file encoding.

But if you are keen, you may change the eclipse.ini file and add the -vmargs -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 to run your eclipse instance with another encoding.

Beware that there are some open bugs regarding that vm parameter for example on Solaris it is ignored.